# npx react-natve generate-bootsplash failing

Tags: react-native

I did setup react-native-bootsplash and generated a splash screen. But after some time when i rerun the command, I'm getting this error:

`npx react-native generate-bootsplash ./assets/icon.png --background-color=3b577c --logo-width=100 --assets-path=./src/assets --flavor=main dyld[24433]: missing symbol called`

It was working just fine, but not anymore ...

"react-native": "0.72.0"
"react-native-bootsplash": "^4.7.5"

deleting node_modules, reinstalling, and the error still persists

Comment: Just found out what is causing this issue. It's another package I use:   "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3".
As soon as I remove   "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3" from devDependencies package.json (not uninstall), "react-native generate-bootsplash" works as expected

Comment: This is the real answer. Thanks 